# When throwing an object, is it copied or moved?

Tags: c++, exception, copy-constructor, throw, move-constructor

As far as I know, thrown objects are copied by default. So the copy constructor should be called when I throw an object. I also know that the compiler may optimize and elide the copying. I have a simple program here where I'm throwing a class called X. It's expected that if I make the class non-copyable, the object can't be thrown. But something unexpected happens. If I delete the copy constructor, the compiler complains about that. If I comment the deletion of the copy constructor and delete the move constructor, the complier complains about deleting the move constructor.
the code:

```
class X
{
public:
    int code;
    X(int code) : code(code) {}
    //X(X&) = delete;
    //X(X&&) = delete;
};

void func()
{
    X x(4);
    throw x;
}

int main() { }
```

The error when I delete the copy constructor:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void func()’:
main.cpp:13:11: error: use of deleted function ‘X::X(X&)’
     throw x;
           ^
```

The error when I delete the move constructor:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void func()’:
main.cpp:13:11: error: use of deleted function ‘X::X(X&&)’
     throw x;
           ^
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Edit: If I delete the copy constructor and provide an implementation for the move constructor, the code works fine. Whereas if I delete the move constructor and provide an Implementation for the copy constructor, I still get the same error. Why can't I delete the move constructor?

code:

```
class X
{
public:
    int code;
    X(int code) : code(code) {}
    X(X&) = default;
    X(X&&) = delete;
};

void func()
{
    X x(5);
    throw x;
}

int main() { }
```

error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void func()’:
main.cpp:13:11: error: use of deleted function ‘X::X(X&&)’
     throw x;
           ^
```

Comment: When you "delete the copy constructor", do you reinstate the move constructor (so that _some_ constructor is left)?

Comment: @StackExchange123 there's little or no difference between deleting either one and both of the constructors. When you delete either of them it would delete the other constructor. When you delete both, it doesn't make any difference either.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It works only if I provide an implementation for the move constructor. If I delete the move constructor, even if I provide an implementation for the copy constructor, I still get the same error.

Comment: @aep Thank you. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

The initialization of the exception object follows the same rules as the initialization of other objects: when the initializer is an lvalue, the copy constructor is used, and when the initializer is an rvalue, the move constructor is used. However, see C++17 [class.copy.elision]/3:

> ... if the operand of a *throw-expression* (8.17) is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost enclosing *try-block* (if there is one), overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated
>   by an rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue. [ *Note:* This two-stage overload resolution must be performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. — *end note* ]

Here, you are throwing the object in a context where it is treated as an rvalue first. If overload resolution fails, it will then be treated as an lvalue. Therefore, in general, the compiler prefers to use the move constructor.

1. When the copy constructor is explicitly deleted, the compiler does not generate the move constructor ([class.copy.ctor]/8), so the code doesn't compile.
2. When the move constructor is explicitly deleted, the first stage of overload resolution selects the move constructor. An error occurs because the function selected by overload resolution is deleted. (Note: a defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted is ignored by overload resolution ([class.copy.ctor]/10). An explicitly deleted move constructor is not ignored by overload resolution.)
3. When both the copy and move constructors are explicitly deleted, the previous paragraph still holds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question. If I delete the move constructor and implement the copy constructor, why the copy constructor isn't being selected?

Comment: @StackExchange123 Deleted functions still participate in overload resolution. When overload resolution selects a deleted function, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @eerorika Which rule?

Comment: @Brian [class.copy.elision]/3, specifically `If the first overload resolution fails ... overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue`. And when the overload resolution is performed for an lvalue, non-deleted the copy constructor is  selected.

Comment: @eerorika If overload resolution selects a deleted function, it succeeds and the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @Brian Does what you've said implies that it's normal to get an error if the copy constructor is defined but the move constructor is deleted? If yes then probably that means that I should always have the copy constructor defined. as eerorika stated in one of the coments: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8YkSh- the code here works on a newer version of gcc and doesn't work on an older version. Can you explain why it works on one and not on the other?

Comment: @Brian ah, so matching a deleted overload does not count as a failed resolution? I guess I don't know failed resolution means then.

Comment: @StackExchange123 I don't know why it compiles on a newer GCC. Maybe they consider it an overload resolution failure when the function is deleted.

Comment: @eerorika I guess it's not explicitly stated anywhere, so it might be unclear what the standard means. This could also explain the discrepancy between compiler versions.

Answer (score 1):

> When throwing an object, is it copied or moved?

The thrown object will be copy-initialised, and the lvalue local object will be treated as an rvalue - same as if returning a local lvalue.

Thus, if the type has a move constructor, then it will be moved in your example. If the class is only copyable but not movable, then it will be copied. Likewise, if the throw expression is not (treated as) an rvalue, then it is copied.

If the type is neither copyable nor movable, then it cannot be thrown. The copy or move may be elided in some cases but that has no effect on whether the type has to be copyable or movable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question. Even if I provide an implementation for the copy constructor when deleting the move constructor, I still get the same error.

Comment: @StackExchange123 Seems to be a problem for MSVC and old GCC, but not a problem for Clang nor new GCC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8YkSh-

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw)

> Even if copy initialization selects the move constructor, copy initialization from lvalue must be well-formed, and the destructor must be accessible (since C++14)

And

> If the type of `expression` is a class type, its copy/move constructor and destructor must be accessible even if copy elision takes place.

Apparently, for well defined exception class a copy constructor is necessary, even if it wouldn't be used. C++11 standard [didn't mandate that](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1863), but it was fixed in C++14.

I'm not 100% sure how to interpret "*This may call the move constructor for rvalue expression*" - whether move constructor is also required or not. For backwards compatibility it shouldn't be, but perhaps someone can quote standard on that.

Comment: It's strange that I get no errors when I delete the copy constructor and Implement the move constructor. I only get errors when deleting the move constructor and implementing the copy constructor.